# Android - Glide failed to load image

Tags: android-studio, android-glide, image-loading

I am trying to load an image into image view through glide library but whenever i run the app, the image view goes blank and log shows failed to load resource

```
dp = view.findViewById(R.id.circleView);

  GlideApp
                                 .with(getActivity())
                                 .load(serverResponse.getMessage().getPic())//C:/Apache24/htdocs/app2/User Files/User Id-102/User id 102.jpg
                                 .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                                     @Override
                                     public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                         // log exception
                                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error loading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                         Log.v("glide", "Error loading image", e);
                                         return false; // important to return false so the error placeholder can be placed
                                     }

                                     @Override
                                     public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                         return false;
                                     }
                                 })
                                 .into(dp);
```

log

```
 2018-11-02 19:20:08.709 31664-31664/com.example.user.myapplication W/Glide: Load failed for C:/Apache24/htdocs/app2/User Files/User Id-102/User id 102.jpg with size [200x200]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
2018-11-02 19:20:08.718 31664-31664/com.example.user.myapplication V/glide: Error loading image
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
```

I cannot figure out actually from where the error is occuring. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance